# What is the difference between ECM and VECM and when to chose one over the other?

Tags: r, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model, ecm

I hope you can help me concerning the following question. It is mainly about when to use ECM or VECM. Suppose i have two time series of daily stock prices from Company Y and X and regression a regression in the form of Y ~ X revealed that the both series are cointegrated (ADF-Test on the regression residuals with p-value at 0.02). Based on that i wanted to build an ECM in R via the ecmSymfit Function. This Function returns two models in the form dY ~ dX(t-1) + dY(t-1) +e(t-1) and dX ~ dY(t-1) + dX(t-1) + e(t-1) where e(t-1) are the residuals from the regression Y~X. As i understood now these two models simply show the reaction of dY and dX given a shock in the previous period via e(t-1)*corresponding coefficient.

But what i read many times now is that proceeding in this form would not be that feasible since one has to determine which of the both stocks is the dependent and independent variable i.e. Y is affecting X or X is affecting Y. And since it could be that both are affecting each other simultaneously a VECM would be required (eventhough i thought before that this would only be required if there are at least more than two time sieries). Could you tell me if it is correct that already here a VECM is required?

And furthermore, do the two models above not already show how the variables are reacting given a shock in the prevous period (via dY ~ dX(t-1) + dY(t-1) + e(t-1) -> shows how Y reacts given a shock in e(t-1) and dX ~ dY(t-1) + dX(t-1) + e(t-1)-> shows how X reacts given a shock in e(t-1)). Or would it be required to construct an additional ECM based on the regression residuals of X~Y?

Any help would be highly appreciated since i am becoming a bit confused on when to use what.

Thanks in advance and best

LD

Comment: Looks like you got it right, i.e. I do not find mistakes in your reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two models you get from the function are ECMs when viewed separately and a VECM when viewed together. You can be interested in one, another or both equations, depending on what kind of inference you want to do (examine effects of the error correction term and/or lags on $X$, on $Y$ or both). A VECM would do the job in any case, but in the first two cases the relevant ECM will be sufficient, too. If you are interested in forecasting $X$, $Y$ or both more than one step ahead, you will need the VECM unless one of the equations contains all zero coefficients.

Comment: Dear Richard, Thank you very much for your feedback! One additional request. I have now a model in the form of dY ~ dX(t-1) + ... + dX(t-n) + dY(t-1) +...+ dY(t-n) + e(t-1), with n=2,...,100. So i included 100 lags of dX and dY in the ECM. As stated above the residuals from the underlying regression Y~X were identified as stationary, although highly autocorrelated. But in the final output the coeffient of the EC-term seems to be insignificant (p-value ~ 0.25). Can this be the case when the underlying residuals are stationary or is it maybe due to the high number of lags included?

Comment: @user14731396, perhaps you have included too many lags or perhaps $Y$ truly does not adjust towards $X$. How long are your time series?

Comment: The time series contains 650 daily closing prices of companies Y and X. I suppose it is due to the amount of lags since when controlling for the adjustment of X the EC-term is insignificant as well-

Comment: 100 lags given 650 data points seems too much. Given that these are stock prices, I would not be surprised if the best forecasting model had zero lags.

Comment: But i need to use lags to make any prediction. Otherwise i would just regress dYt ~ dXt + e(t-1) and since i dont know dXt this would not be feasible for making predictions or am i wrong? Although you are of course right that this results in the best R^2.

Comment: It cannot yield the highest $R^2$; the more regressors you have, the higher the $R^2$. But this is not the relevant question here. For forecasting, the model is capable of predicting multiple steps ahead regardless of how many lags you include.

Comment: Yes but the adjusted R^2 accounts for the the additional regressors right? And when comparing dY ~ dX(t-1) + ... + dX(t-n) + dY(t-1) +...+ dY(t-n) + e(t-1) vs. dY(t) ~ dX(t) + e(t-1) they lead to approx. the same Adj. R^2, at least that is what i can see from my output in R. And sorry for asking again, but how can i do a prediction based on a model like dY(t) ~ a*dX(t) + b*e(t-1) when dX(t) occurs on the same point in time as my variable i want to predict (dY(t)). I hope that i do not cause to much confusion, i am quite new to Econometrics and thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user14731396, the ECM and VECM have only lagged predictors on the right hand side. You need to lag anything that is contemporaneous when you are including it on the right hand side. An ECM with zero lags would be $\Delta y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1\text{ect}_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$ where $\text{ect}$ is the error-correction term (the stationary linear combination of $y$ and $x$). $\beta_0$ may be zero, otherwise you get a drift in $y_t$.

Comment: Ok with zero lags you meant Δyt=β0+β1ect(t−1)+εt, so only regressing on the error-correction-term. Misunderstanding from my side. Thank you!